# How to add C++ "int" to HashSet<Integer>?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

How to pass a cpp set value to java HashSet through JNI?

```
jobject getJintSet(std::set<int> *stdSet){
      if (stdSet == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }
        JniMethodInfo t;
        JniHelper::getMethodInfo(t
                                 , "java/util/HashSet"
                                 , "<init>"
                                 , "(I)V");
        jobject ret = t.env->NewObject(t.classID, t.methodID,stdSet->size());

        JniHelper::getMethodInfo(t
                                 , "java/util/HashSet"
                                 , "add"
                                 , "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z");

        for (std::set<int>::iterator it = stdSet->begin(); it != stdSet->end(); it++) {
            jobject k = *it;
            t.env->CallObjectMethod(ret, t.methodID, k); //Here is the problem 
           //the HashSet object type is Integer but a cpp int value is being passed,
          // then it crashed.

        }
        return ret;
}
```

Comment: Just a guess but it looks like you need to convert `stdSet` to a `HashSet<int>` and _then_ call `CallObjectMethod()`.

Answer (score 0):

Java's generics are implemented with type erasure. So, the HashSet can have whatever types you put in it. Of course, it would part of the method contract to return a HashSet of a certain type.

If want to add an `Integer` value, you have to create an "Ljava/lang/Integer;" object.

If you'd rather add an `int` value, just type `k` as a `jint` instead of `jobject` to match your use of "Z".